# Bertopic assign topics to data frame

Tags: python, text-classification, bert-language-model, topic-modeling

I have build a topic model with Bertopic.
After getting topic how could I assign them to dataset.

My main aim is to convert unsupervised topic modelling to supervised multi label classification problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: In general this 'conversion' doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can write the topics directly with the original data set in a dataframe because the topics are output in the same order as they are contained in the docs.

```
import pandas as pd 
model =  BERTopic.load('path')
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'topic': model.topics_,'document': docs['id']})
```

Comment: I wish there was a proper way of doing it but this works. Thanks @padul